# Lon and Lat flipped when converting MODIS to Lat Lon

Tags: coordinate-system, modis, python-3

I found a code online that plots MCD19A2 tiles correctly, but I need to make manipulations to the data, and not just plot directly so I am making my own code for that.

I basically copied the code I found online to make the reprojection to lat-lon, but when I plot it under the same instructions I get the x/y axis flipped. If I change Lon to Lat and Lat to Lon it plots correctly and I can't figure out why that is happening.

Correct:
[image: Correct picture]

Wrong:
[image: Wrong picture]

Code:

```
import os
import re
import pyproj
from pyproj import Transformer

import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime
from osgeo import gdal
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd

from pyhdf.SD import SD, SDC
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap


FILE_NAME = 'MCD19A2/MCD19A2.A2019293.h11v11.006.2019303225408.hdf'
DATAFIELD_NAME = 'Optical_Depth_055'

basename = os.path.basename(FILE_NAME)
pngfile = "{0}".format(basename)

## Get tile 
def get_tile_shp(fname, resolution):
    basedir = "MODIS_sinu_grid"
    tile = fname.split(".")[-4]
    geo_pkg_name = f"{basedir}/{resolution}/{tile}.gpkg"
    res=float(resolution.replace("km", "").replace("m", "000"))
    ##
    try:
        print("      ...Reading grid details for tile ", tile, flush=True)
        shp=gpd.read_file(geo_pkg_name, driver="GPKG")
        print("         ...Done ", flush=True)
        return shp
    except:
        print("      ...Creating grid details for tile ", tile, flush=True)
        ## Open dataset
        hdf = SD(fname, SDC.READ) 

        ## Get info
        gridmeta = hdf.attributes(full=1)["StructMetadata.0"][0]

        ## Get corners
        ul_regex = re.compile(r'''UpperLeftPointMtrs=\((?P<upper_left_x>[+-]?\d+\.\d+),(?P<upper_left_y>[+-]?\d+\.\d+)\)''', re.VERBOSE)
        match = ul_regex.search(gridmeta)
        x0 = float(match.group('upper_left_x'))
        y0 = float(match.group('upper_left_y'))

        lr_regex = re.compile(r'''LowerRightMtrs=\((?P<lower_right_x>[+-]?\d+\.\d+),(?P<lower_right_y>[+-]?\d+\.\d+)\)''', re.VERBOSE)
        match = lr_regex.search(gridmeta)
        x1 = float(match.group('lower_right_x'))
        y1 = float(match.group('lower_right_y'))

        ## Construct the grid
        nx=ny=int(1200/res)
        x = np.linspace(x0, x1, nx)
        y = np.linspace(y0, y1, ny)
        xv, yv = np.meshgrid(x, y)

 
        ## Convert to lat-lon
        sinu = pyproj.Proj("+proj=sinu +R=6371007.181 +nadgrids=@null +wktext")
        wgs84 = pyproj.Proj("EPSG:4326") 
        lon, lat= pyproj.transform(sinu, wgs84, xv, yv)
        lon[lon < -180] += 360
        lat[lat < -90] += 180

        ## Create geodataframe
        df_lon=pd.DataFrame(lon).stack() 
        df_lat=pd.DataFrame(lat).stack() 
        df=pd.concat([df_lat, df_lon], axis=1, keys=["lat", "lon"])
        df=df.rename_axis(["i_lon", "i_lat"]).reset_index()

        ## Save to file
        gdf=gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(df.lon, df.lat), crs="epsg:4326")   

        #
        ## Not finishing for some reason?
        os.remove(geo_pkg_name)
        gdf.to_file(geo_pkg_name, driver="GPKG")
        #gdf.to_file(geo_pkg_name.replace("gpkg", "geojson"), driver="GeoJSON") 
        print("      ...Saving to: ", geo_pkg_name, flush=True)
        print("         ...Done ", flush=True)
        return gdf

## Read dataset to geodataframe
def read_dataset_to_df(file, date, var, new_var, resolution):
    fname = 'HDF4_EOS:EOS_GRID:"%s":grid%s:%s'%(file, resolution, var)

    ## Open dataset
    gdset = gdal.Open(fname)
    if new_var=="QA":
        data=np.array(gdset.ReadAsArray(), dtype='uint16') 
    else:
        data = gdset.ReadAsArray()

    ## Get info for each orbit
    dfs=[]
    oamount =  int(gdset.GetMetadata()['Orbit_amount'])
    otime =  gdset.GetMetadata()['Orbit_time_stamp'].split()
    for i in range(oamount): 
        ## Convert data to dataframe
        df = pd.DataFrame(data[i]).stack() 
        df = pd.DataFrame(df, columns=[new_var]) 

        ## Aqua or Terra
        df["Satelite"]=otime[i][-1]

        ## Hour
        hour=otime[i][-5:-1]
        ## Date
        df["time"]=datetime(date.year, date.month, date.day, int(hour[:2]), int(hour[2:])) 
        #df.loc[df[new_var]<0, new_var]=np.nan

        ## Append data
        dfs.append(df.dropna())


    #indexes=[tuple(c) for c in grid[["i_lat", "i_lon"]].values]
    df=pd.concat(dfs).rename_axis(["i_lon", "i_lat"]).reset_index()
    #df=df[df.index.isin(indexes)].reset_index()
    df.index=df["time"]
    df.index.name=None

    if new_var=="QA":
        df["QA"]=df["QA"].astype(int).apply(lambda x: '{0:016b}'.format(x)) 
        df["Cloud_Mask"]=df["QA"].str[-3:].apply(int, args=(2,) ) 
        df["Land-Water_Mask"]=df["QA"].str[-5:-3].apply(int, args=(2,) ) 
        #df["Adjacency_Mask"]=df["QA"].str[-8:-5].apply(int, args=(2,) ) 
        #df["Glint_Mask"]=df["QA"].str[-13].apply(int, args=(2,) )  
        #df["Aerosol-Model_Mask"]=df["QA"].str[-15:-13].apply(int, args=(2,) ) 
        df["QA-AOD_Mask"]=df["QA"].str[-12:-8].apply(int, args=(2,) ) 
    
    return df

## Plots tile correctly. Code retrieved from the internet
def works_fine(name):
    """
    Copyright (C) 2014-2019 The HDF Group
    Copyright (C) 2014 John Evans

    This example code illustrates how to access and visualize an LP DAAC MCD19A2
    v6 HDF-EOS2 Sinusoidal Grid file in Python.

    If you have any questions, suggestions, or comments on this example, please use
    the HDF-EOS Forum (http://hdfeos.org/forums).  If you would like to see an
    example of any other NASA HDF/HDF-EOS data product that is not listed in the
    HDF-EOS Comprehensive Examples page (http://hdfeos.org/zoo), feel free to
    contact us at eoshelp@hdfgroup.org or post it at the HDF-EOS Forum
    (http://hdfeos.org/forums).

    Usage:  save this script and run

        $python MCD19A2.A2010010.h25v06.006.2018047103710.hdf.py


    Tested under: Python 3.7.3 :: Anaconda custom (64-bit)
    Last updated: 2019-09-20
    """
    hdf = SD(FILE_NAME, SDC.READ)

    # Read dataset.
    data3D = hdf.select(DATAFIELD_NAME)
    data = data3D[:,:,:].astype(np.double)
    data = np.mean(data, axis=0)

    # Read attributes.
    attrs = data3D.attributes(full=1)
    lna=attrs["long_name"]
    long_name = lna[0]
    vra=attrs["valid_range"]
    valid_range = vra[0]
    fva=attrs["_FillValue"]
    _FillValue = fva[0]
    sfa=attrs["scale_factor"]
    scale_factor = sfa[0]        
    ua=attrs["unit"]
    units = ua[0]
    aoa=attrs["add_offset"]
    add_offset = aoa[0]

    # Apply the attributes to the data.

    #invalid = np.logical_or(data < valid_range[0], data > valid_range[1])
    #invalid = np.logical_or(invalid, data == _FillValue)
    #data[invalid] = np.nan
    data = (data - add_offset) * scale_factor
    data = np.ma.masked_array(data, np.isnan(data))

    # Construct the grid.  The needed information is in a global attribute
    # called 'StructMetadata.0'.  Use regular expressions to tease out the
    fattrs = hdf.attributes(full=1)
    ga = fattrs["StructMetadata.0"]
    gridmeta = ga[0]
    ul_regex = re.compile(r'''UpperLeftPointMtrs=\((?P<upper_left_x>[+-]?\d+\.\d+),(?P<upper_left_y>[+-]?\d+\.\d+)\)''', re.VERBOSE)

    match = ul_regex.search(gridmeta)
    x0 = float(match.group('upper_left_x'))
    y0 = float(match.group('upper_left_y'))

    lr_regex = re.compile(r'''LowerRightMtrs=\((?P<lower_right_x>[+-]?\d+\.\d+),(?P<lower_right_y>[+-]?\d+\.\d+)\)''', re.VERBOSE)
    match = lr_regex.search(gridmeta)
    x1 = float(match.group('lower_right_x'))
    y1 = float(match.group('lower_right_y'))

    nx, ny = data.shape
    x = np.linspace(x0, x1, nx)
    y = np.linspace(y0, y1, ny)
    xv, yv = np.meshgrid(x, y)


    sinu = pyproj.Proj("+proj=sinu +R=6371007.181 +nadgrids=@null +wktext")
    wgs84 = pyproj.Proj("+init=EPSG:4326") 

    transformer = Transformer.from_proj(sinu, wgs84)
    lon, lat = transformer.transform(xv, yv)

    km =int(1200/nx)

    m = Basemap(projection='cyl', resolution='l',
                llcrnrlat=np.min(lat), urcrnrlat = np.max(lat),
                llcrnrlon=np.min(lon), urcrnrlon = np.max(lon))                
    m.drawcoastlines(linewidth=0.5)
    m.drawparallels(np.arange(np.floor(np.min(lat)), np.ceil(np.max(lat)), 5), labels=[1, 0, 0, 0])
    m.drawmeridians(np.arange(np.floor(np.min(lon)), np.ceil(np.max(lon)), 5), labels=[0, 0, 0, 1])

    m.pcolormesh(lon, lat, data, latlon=True)
    cb = m.colorbar()

    fig = plt.gcf()
    fig.savefig(name)
    plt.clf()

## My code that I am trying to fix because I need more processing
def doesnt_work(name):

    data_all=read_dataset_to_df(FILE_NAME, datetime(2019, 10, 21), var=DATAFIELD_NAME, new_var="AOD", resolution="1km")
    data_all=data_all.groupby(["i_lon", "i_lat"]).mean()


    geo_pkg_name="MODIS_sinu_grid/1km/h11v11.gpkg"
    grid_tile=get_tile_shp(FILE_NAME, "1km")

    data=grid_tile.merge(data_all, on=["i_lat", "i_lon"], how="outer")

    ## Works flipped
    #lat=data["lon"].values.reshape(1200,1200)
    #lon=data["lat"].values.reshape(1200,1200)
    ## Doesnt work
    lat=data["lat"].values.reshape(1200,1200)
    lon=data["lon"].values.reshape(1200,1200)

    ## Data
    data=data["AOD"].values.reshape(1200,1200)


    m = Basemap(projection='cyl', resolution='l',
                llcrnrlat=np.min(lat), urcrnrlat = np.max(lat),
                llcrnrlon=np.min(lon), urcrnrlon = np.max(lon))                
    m.drawcoastlines(linewidth=0.5)
    m.drawparallels(np.arange(np.floor(np.min(lat)), np.ceil(np.max(lat)), 5), labels=[1, 0, 0, 0])
    m.drawmeridians(np.arange(np.floor(np.min(lon)), np.ceil(np.max(lon)), 5), labels=[0, 0, 0, 1])

    m.pcolormesh(lon, lat, data, latlon=True)
    cb = m.colorbar()

    fig = plt.gcf()
    fig.savefig(name)
    plt.clf()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    doesnt_work(pngfile  + "_wrong.png")
    works_fine(pngfile  + "_correct.png")
```

I know I haven't removed invalid data, I am leaving it so that the map is easier to read to determine if it's done correctly or wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The snippet of code that did the reprojection in the one that didn't work was:

```
## Convert to lat-lon
sinu = pyproj.Proj("+proj=sinu +R=6371007.181 +nadgrids=@null +wktext")
wgs84 = pyproj.Proj("EPSG:4326") 
lon, lat= pyproj.transform(sinu, wgs84, xv, yv)
```

Which was different than the example code I found so I changed the `pyproj` function that did the transformation

```
## Convert to lat-lon
sinu = pyproj.Proj("+proj=sinu +R=6371007.181 +nadgrids=@null +wktext")
wgs84 = pyproj.Proj("EPSG:4326") 
transformer = Transformer.from_proj(sinu, wgs84)
lon, lat = transformer.transform(xv, yv)
```

But that also didn't change things and the axis were still flipped. Then I noticed the way to initialize the `wgs84` projection was different and edited that to look like

```
sinu = pyproj.Proj("+proj=sinu +R=6371007.181 +nadgrids=@null +wktext")
wgs84 = pyproj.Proj("+init=EPSG:4326") 
transformer = Transformer.from_proj(sinu, wgs84)
lon, lat = transformer.transform(xv, yv)
```

And it works! I don't know, but now the longitudes are the longitudes and the latitudes are the latitudes.

For the record I am using pyproj 3.3.1 and Python 3.10.4

Answer (score 0):

When I use wgs84 = pyproj.Proj("EPSG:4326"), the latitude and longitude are swapped.
And when I use wgs84 = pyproj.Proj("+init=EPSG:4326"), the latitude and longitude are normal.